# ITEXT PDFReader not able to read PDF

Tags: itext, pdf-reader

I am not able to read a PDF file using [itext](/questions/tagged/itext) [pdfreader](/questions/tagged/pdfreader). This PDf is valid PDF if I tried to open this.

URL Of PDF: http://www.fundslibrary.co.uk/FundsLibrary.DataRetrieval/Documents.aspx?type=fund_class_kiid&id=f096b13b-3d0e-4580-8d3d-87cf4d002650&user=fidelitydocumentreport

Comment: Please share your PDF, and the code you use to read it. Without both, your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Please open the PDF in Adobe Reader, then use "Save as" and save a copy of the file under a new name. You will notice that iText's `PdfReader` can open that file. This is an indication that your allegation that the PDF is valid is false. On which grounds do you base that allegation? Not all PDFs that can be opened in Adobe Reader are valid.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, I tried your comment but error is same. I am using Itext 5.5.10. Its reading simple file but when i try complex pdf file It throws error.  Your suggestions are always welcome....

Answer (score 0):

The PDF in question is encrypted.

According to the PDF specification,

> Encryption applies to all strings and streams in the document's PDF file, with the following exceptions:
>
> - The values for the ID entry in the trailer
> - Any strings in an Encrypt dictionary
> - Any strings that are inside streams such as content streams and compressed object streams, which themselves are encrypted

Later on there are information on special cases in which the document level metadata stream is not encrypted either or in which only attachments are encrypted.

---

The Cross-Reference Stream Dictionary of the PDF looks like this:

```
<<
/Root 101 0 R
/Info 63 0 R
/XRef(stream)
/Encrypt 103 0 R
/ID[<D034DE62220E1CBC2642AC517F0FE9C7><D034DE62220E1CBC2642AC517F0FE9C7>]
/Type/XRef
/W[1 3 2]
/Index[0 107]
/Size 107
/Length 642
>>
```

As you can see there is an non-encrypted string here, `(stream)`, which is neither the value for the ID entry, nor in an Encrypt dictionary, nor inside a stream. Furthermore, the afore mentioned special cases do not apply here either.

Thus, this file violates the PDF specification here. Therefore, **this file is not a valid PDF**.

---

Furthermore, according to the PDF specification

> The last line of the file shall contain only the end-of-file marker, %%EOF.

The file at handsends like this

[image: Screenshot of last lines of file]

Thus, the last line of the file does contain something else than the end-of-file marker (which is in the line before), a 0x06 and a 0x0c.

The file, therefore, violates the PDF specification here, too.